# password_hash giving error: Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: php, database, password-encryption

Edit: My issue has been resolved. I did not know or think of bindValue(), that is why I do not think this is a duplicate question. Thanks for the help!

I am learning how to register users with PHP and it seems like password_hash is giving me the "Only Variables should be passed by reference" error message. I've seen many people with the same error, but it does not seem to apply to my case (in my opinion).

connecting to database

```
$server = 'localhost';
$username ='root';
$password ='root';
$database = 'register_test';

try{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database;" , $username, $password);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die ("Connection failed" . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Registering user

```
require 'database.php';
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])):

$pass = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "Insert into user (email, password) values (:email, :password)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt ->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt ->bindParam(':password', password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)); //error showns here

if($stmt -> execute() ):
  die('Success');
else:
  die('Fail');
endif;
endif;
```

If you guys need more information please let me know.

Comment: Use `$stmt->bindValue()` instead of `$stmt->bindParam()`.

Comment: Your query won't work anyways. you're specifying one field to insert into, and providing two values.

Comment: Marc B. I was trying out a few things and forgot to put 'password' back into the insert statement. Thanks for noticing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`PDOStatement::bindValue()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php) instead of [`PDOStatement::bindParam()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

From the docs:

> Unlike PDOStatement::bindValue(), the variable is **bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called**.

So, your code becomes:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindValue(':password', password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

The result of a function cannot be passed by reference when `E_STRICT` mode is enabled, without triggering a warning. By using `bindValue()` instead, we pass the return value of the function as a copy, basically.

Comment: Thanks. That did remove the error message, but I do have a new problem. The email and password shows '0' and '0' respectively on the database.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Hmm. What does it show if you `var_dump()` `$email` and `$pass`? You might have to post a separate question if it's not something simple.

Comment: var_dump() is showing the correct characters that I input. I recreated the table and it's now working fine. Thanks very much for the help!